# Tricky extending of mongoid model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Having two models: Car (e.g Audi, Mercedes) and Option (ABS, Laser Headlights, Night Vision ...). Car habtm options.

Suppose both for Audi and Mercedes "Night Vision" option is available.
But to have it in Mercedes you need to pay some extra money for this option. So as I'm guessing I need to extend somehow my Option model to store options's extra price for some cars. Car model I think should also be modified. But can't imagine how.

My aim to achieve behaviour something like this:

Audi.options.night_vision.extra_price => nil

Mercedes.options.night_vision.extra_price => 300

Of course I don't want to duplicate "Night Vision" option in options collection for every car.

Thanks.

Comment: audi.options.night_vision.extra_price(audi) but not elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

This is neither the simplest, or most elegant, just an idea that should work based on assumptions on how you may have implemented the options. Please come back to me if you need more help.

To achieve audi.options.night_vision.extra_price I assume that you have a models such as:

```
class car
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, type: String
   has_and_belongs_to_many :options do
     def night_vision
       @target.find_by(name:'night_vision')
     end
   end
end

class option
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, type: String
   field :extra_price, type: Float
   has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
end
```

This would enable you to do:

```
audi = Car.find_by(name:'audi')
audi.options.night_vision.extra_price
```

If the above assumptions are correct, you should be able to mod your classes like so:

```
class option
   include Mongoid::Document
   attr_accessor :extra_price
   field :name, type: String
   has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
   embeds_many :extras 
end

class extra
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :car_id, type: String
   field :price, type: String
   embedded_in :option
end

class car
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, type: String
   has_and_belongs_to_many :options do
     def night_vision
       extra = @target.find_by(name:'night_vision')
       extra_price = extra.prices.find_by(car_id: @target._id.to_s) if extra
       extra.extra_price = extra_price.price if extra && extra_price
       return extra
     end
     def find_or_create_option(args)
         extra = @target.find_or_create_by(name:args)
         price = extra.extras.find_or_create_by(car_id:@target._id.to_s)
         price.set(price: args.price
     end
   end
end
```

This should then enable you to populate your options like:

```
audi.options.find_or_create_option({name:'night_vision', price:2310.30})
bmw.options.find_or_create_option({name:'night_vision', price:1840.99})

audi.options.night_vision.extra_price
=> 2310.30
bmw.options.night_vision.extra_price
=> 1840.99
```

And if you attempted to find night_vision on a car that did not have night_vision you would get:

```
skoda.options.night_vision
=> nil
skoda.options.night_vision.extra_price
=> NoMethodError (undefined method 'extra_price' for nil:NilClass)
```

Comment: Glad you came up with a solution. I didn't recommend that way due you wanting the scope of .night_vision so that you could do audi.options.night_vision.extra_price rather than audi.options.first.extra_price

Comment: sorry for misleading you. Actually audi.options.night_vision.extra_price was some sort of pseudo code. Cars has tons of options so scoping each option have not much sense.